# IBM Worklight - Can't run an app on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, jmx, mbeans

My app runs well on Worklight Development Server, but not on WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile.

I tried both Oracle JDK and IBM JDK, there was no difference.
There was no problem connecting to the server with jconsole, although I had to connect without ssl.

On Eclipse Console,

```
[2014-07-11 17:18:10]             Starting build process: application 'U1', all environments 
[2014-07-11 17:18:12]             Application 'U1' with all environments build finished.
[2014-07-11 17:18:12]             Deploying application 'U1' with all environments to Worklight Server... 
[2014-07-11 17:19:02]             Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: : JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans. Reason: "FWLSE3012E: JMX configuration 
error. Unable to obtain MBeans. Reason: "Connection refused".".
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not enough information. What is the full Liberty version? What is your Java version? Which guide did you follow and how did you deploy the .war file to the application server?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how the Studio deploys to an external Liberty server.

You could also:
    Install Worklight Server and deploy using 
          - the Server Configuration Tool
          - or the ant tasks (provided by the Worklight Server installer)
          - or manual procedure documented at https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_wlconsole_install.html

The manual procedure may give you hints about what is missing in your External Liberty Server.
It could be:
   - rest connector and it's configuration https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_optional_config_app_server_liberty.html
   - JNDI properties so that Liberty can use the REST connector (step 3 at https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_for_wladmin_manually.html )