# IBM Worklight 6.2: JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I have IBM Worklight 6.2 development environment with the following setup.

1. Oracle Java 1.7
2. Eclipse 4.3
3. IBM Worklight 6.2 Developer Edition

A sample Hybrid project had been created and deployed in the Worklight development server and app works fine in the Mobile Browser Simulator.

I am getting the following error in Worklight Server console in Eclipse:

**[ERROR ] Failed to obtain JMX connection to access an MBean.**

**There might be a JMX configuration error: Read timed out**

**[ERROR ] FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.**

**FWLSE3012E: JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans. Reason: "Read timed out".**

And also I am getting the following error in Worklight Console[Web Console].

**FWLSE3012E: JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans. Reason: "Read timed out".**

Note:
I have read the following questions but no luck.

1. [IBM Worklight - Can't run an app on WebSphere Application Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694418/ibm-worklight-cant-run-an-app-on-websphere-application-server)
2. [How to solve management service not starting up in Worklight 6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518336/how-to-solve-management-service-not-starting-up-in-worklight-6-2)

Additional Info:

I used to get the following error whenever the Worklight development server is started from eclipse.

*[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.

[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.

[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.

[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.

[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.

[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.*

I hope necessary information's I have provided. Let me know if u still need.

Comment: The warnings at the bottom are unrelated and can be ignored; this is a known issue in Worklight 6.2 and a fix will be released to address it. It seems to happen intermittently. Typically a restart of the server or waiting for a while resolves it before refreshing the Worklight Console,

Comment: Thanks @IdanAdar. Is this the same case with IBM Worklight 6.2 License Edition?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference between the editions in regards to this issue.

Comment: @IdanAdar, Do I need to raise PMR?

Comment: You can if you want to.

Comment: Try to edit the file WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/jvm.options in your Eclipse workspace, adding the line -Dcom.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.readTimeout=180000 . Then stop and restart the Worklight Development Server. Does this help?

Comment: A similar hint as slowhand that may help: Try to edit the file WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/server.xml and add in the <server> section the following line, then restart and try again: <executor name="LargeThreadPool" id="default" coreThreads="40" maxThreads="80" keepAlive="60s" stealPolicy="STRICT" rejectedWorkPolicy="CALLER_RUNS" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMX timeout error in Worklight 6.2 is a known issue.

Typically when this error occurs to me, a way to resolve it is to either 'wait' a while and then to stop & restart the Worklight Server (in Eclipse > Servers view > 'play' button). Another option is to restart Eclipse.

You can also try the suggestions from the comments:

> Try to edit the file
>   WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/jvm.options in your Eclipse
>   workspace, adding the line
>   "-Dcom.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.readTimeout=180000". Then stop and restart the Worklight Development Server.

and

> Try to edit the file
>   WorklightServerConfig/servers/worklight/server.xml and add in the
>    section the following line, then restart and try again:
>
> `<executor name="LargeThreadPool" id="default" coreThreads="40"
>   maxThreads="80" keepAlive="60s" stealPolicy="STRICT"
>   rejectedWorkPolicy="CALLER_RUNS" />`

Best is [to open a PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) (support ticket) and request an iFix as this is due to be fixed.

Comment: I believe so. Did you try updating your Worklight Studio to the latest? should be from August 1st.

Comment: I am having this same issue in IBM MobileFirst studio 6.3 on my MacBook Pro. The suggested changes to the threadpool and the read timeout in the jvm.options are already applied in the default configuration. Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: On win 7, Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, MobileFirst 6.3.0 I get the same error. All hints above have been already in.