# IBM Worklight 6.2: JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans Reason: "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have IBM Worklight 6.2 development environment with the following setup.

Oracle Java 1.7/ Eclipse 4.3/ IBM Worklight 6.2 Developer Edition

A sample Hybrid project had been created and deployed in the Worklight development server and app works fine in the Mobile Browser Simulator.

I am getting the following error in Worklight Server console in Eclipse:

```
Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: : JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans. 
Reason: "FWLSE3012E: JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans. Reason: "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?".".
```

Comment: What is your exact Eclipse version? (Java EE? 4.3.2?) What is your exact Worklight version (full build number, Eclipse > Help > About); also consider searching: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworklight%5D+jmx+no+mbean+is%3Aquestion

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM Worklight 6.2: JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721416/ibm-worklight-6-2-jmx-configuration-error-unable-to-obtain-mbeans)

Comment: Why do you think the WLT/MobileFirst questions always get immediately down voted? It seems to look more like reputation management than authentic community curation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532273/unrecognized-ssl-message-plaintext-connection-exception), the error message means that a JMX connection over HTTPS is attempted, when in fact the server speaks the HTTP protocol on that port.

Review the settings that determine the protocol and port used for JMX. See the [set of JNDI properties for Worklight administration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/r_wladmin_jndi_property_list.html?lang=en) and the [set of JNDI properties for Worklight projects](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html?lang=en), and check their values.