# JMX connection to access MBean

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, windows-8.1, jmx, mbeans

My environment:

- O/S: Windows 8.1
- JRE: 1.7
- Eclipse: Luna, 4.4
- Worklight: 6.2 (build 6.2.0.00-20140801-1709)

I have encountered the following error when Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server.
I've re-installed several times, but the error persist.
Another strange thing noted: Need to change the `<httpEndpoint host="*" to host="hostname" ...>` in the server.xml before the Worklight Server can be started.

Questions:

1. Is there any similar problem?
2. Is Worklight Studio tested on Windows 8.1? (based on Announcement Letter, Worklight is only supported on Windows 8)?

> [ERROR   ] Failed to obtain JMX connection to access an MBean.  There
>   might be a JMX configuration error: Connection refused: connect
>
> [ERROR   ] Failed to obtain JMX connection to access an MBean.  There
>   might be a JMX configuration error: FWLSE3012E: JMX configuration
>   error. Unable to obtain MBeans. Reason: "Connection refused: connect".
>
> [ERROR   ] FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.  FWLSE3012E: JMX
>   configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans. Reason: "FWLSE3012E: JMX
>   configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans. Reason: "Connection
>   refused: connect"

Comment: Could it be like this: If <httpEndpoint host="*"> prevented the server from starting, it looks like you had another server already listening on the same port. Then, later on, that other server was shut down, which resulted in the "Connection refused" messages.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the solutions provided in the following questions?

- [IBM Worklight 6.2: JMX configuration error. Unable to obtain MBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721416/ibm-worklight-6-2-jmx-configuration-error-unable-to-obtain-mbeans)
- Also try with JRE 1.6 (make sure Eclipse is configured to use it, too)

Comment: 2. I have another setup with Windows 7, Luna 4.4, Worklight: 6.2 (build 6.2.0.00-20140801-1709), with JRE 7. Not issue observed.

Comment: We have tested on the following environment
[Works] Win7,JRE7,Luna4.4,Worklight6.2 (6.2.0.00-20140801-1709)
[Works] Win8,JRE7,Luna4.4,Worklight6.2 (6.2.0.00-20140801-1709)
[NonWorking] Win8.1,JRE7,Luna4.4,Worklight6.2 (6.2.0.00-20140801-1709)