# IBM Mobilefirst: Installation in redhat linux without admin access

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

We have to do a mobilefirst cli(*version 6.3.0.00.20150106-1724*) build and deploy in our staging environment in a redhat linux machine(details of the env below), however there is no admin access for our team to execute the commands now due to internal infosec policy issues.

When we do execute the following command, there are no errors,

> mfp start
>
> mfp build

But however when we run

> mfp deploy

The response is

```
Error: Project's runtime is not available in the server.
Error: Restart the server by running 'mobilefirst restart' from the current folder
```

Even after doing a `mobilefirst restart` we end up in the same error above.

Current deployment environment is :

```
RHEL version used: rhel-2.5.3.1.e16-x86_64 u71-b14
JAVA version - Java "1.7.0._71" 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

I also doubt it may be because of OpenJDK, do we need Oracle Java only ?

Please help.

Update:

As mentioned by Karl - tail -f on log/console.log

The error is

```
[ERROR] Failed to obtain JMX connection to access MBean
There might be a JMX configuration error: connection time out
[WARNING] No running mbxbeans found
```

Comment: Try with Oracle Java and see if there is any difference then maybe?

Comment: Updated the question @IdanAdar - the summary of the erro is :[ERROR] Failed to obtain JMX connection to access MBean. Will this be still because of open jdk.

Answer (score 1):

Please also run the command with the -d (debug) flag, as it may provide more details. Also run "mfp logs" and examine the tail of the presented server log file for clues.  Finally, run "mfp info" for a dump of your environment. Hopefully in one of those we can find a clue to your issue.

From Idan's comment about Java, be sure you are not using Java 1.8 that is now rolling out, as Worklight server does not yet support that version.  Use v1.7.

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I just verified things work on my Unbuntu 64 machine using openJdk 7. Sorry, I don't have a RedHat vm available to test against.

Comment: Updated the question, the error is [ERROR] Failed to obtain JMX connection to access MBean. I believe still will this be because of Open JDK ?

Comment: That's unrelated. Have you tried googling the error? try the suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721416/ibm-worklight-6-2-jmx-configuration-error-unable-to-obtain-mbeans